# Java: String.format with flag '+' for RTL device language put sign after number

Tags: java, string-formatting, right-to-left

The problem in my Anbdroid app is arosen when `String.format` is used with flag `+` (leading sign before number), and current language is RTL (in my case, Hebrew). The code string is, e.g.,:

```
String.format(Locale.US, "%+06.2f", n)
```

For `n=2`, result is +02.00 (expected) when the device language is English or any other LTR one, but result is 02.00+ (unexpected) when the device language is Hebrew. So the sign for RTL is at the end of given number, despite of `Locale.US` as the first argument in `String.format`.

The question is: how to correctly use flag `+` in a case when device language is RTL?

PS

It has appeared to be on emulator only, on the real device it is surpisingly Ok. I'm sorry that didn't firstly check the problem on the real device, relying on AVD emulator of Android Studio.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Try `Locale.ENGLISH` (instead of `Locale.US`).